# Preventing double touch events by if condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, css

I'm building a module for a responsive website that allows the user to tap the initial screen and expose a panel from the right. They can then tap a close button and close the panel.

The issue is that if the user taps more than once before the panel finishing animating over, it applies double the action moving the panel too far left irreversibly.

I'm new to JS and can't figure out how to solve this. I thought it could be done with a var and if statement but it doesn't seem to be working.

I set up var

```
  pstatus = 1;
```

Then I wrapped each event in an if statement but it's not working. I left it without the if statements so it's functional to review.

Any help would be much appreciated!

http://codepen.io/bsley/pen/kjBcz

On your iPhone (Safari) http://codepen.io/bsley/debug/kjBcz

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to solve this from Javascript, but from Objective C what you would do is to set the button to disabled=YES in the action method, and then set it to disabled=NO once the animation is complete.

I assume the solution would be similar from Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

i would try to do it like this:

1) on click, slide happens.

2) while sliding, click becomes disabled.

3) when finished sliding, click becomes re-enabled.

Comment: Right! This is what I was attempting to do with pstatus but my syntax must be off. http://codepen.io/bsley/pen/xdEvH

Answer (score 0):

You can create a javascript "lock":

```
var lock = false;
$("#MyElement").on("namespace.click", function(){
    if(!lock){
        lock = true;
        //Move Element
        lock = false;
    }
});
```

However, I would suggest looking into Underscore.js and utilizing the throttle() method: http://underscorejs.org/

You can simulate this by replacing:

```
lock = false;
```

With:

```
customThrottle();


var timerDuration = //Duration to wait in milliseconds;
function customThrottle(){
    setTimeout(function(){
            lock = false;
        },
        timerDuration
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks man! This is essentially what I was attempting with pstatus. I've got it implemented but it's not locking quick enough apparently. http://codepen.io/bsley/pen/JpDcy Any idea how to get around this?

Comment: I found a temporary solution just making the "marginLeft" to 0 rather than the incremental value. It's not great but it works for now.

Comment: From just a glance, you are unlocking immediately after using the "animate" call.  Since animate takes place over several milliseconds, it was implemented as a non-blocking call.  This means you are releasing the lock immediately after calling animate() and not after it is finished animating the element. this means you can continue clicking while the animation is going on.  Since you want to use animate(), I would set the animation duration as a variable and then call a method that releases the lock after that duration (via setTimeout)